# How to override allure result folder automatically before every test run

Tags: overriding, report, allure

After generating allure report using allure serve command, I saw that I got my old test run results also in my report. This is because my allure result folder containing old log files in it. How to override this folder before every run. Is there any code that I can add in before test method ?

I am trying to run test and generate allure report.

Comment: What do you use for testing?

Comment: `allure serve` just serves your report files from last run. Which can contain old data(history) from all previous run. But that is not the default setting(keeping the history). You have to manually implement it.